# call a method only on successful execution of run method of thread class in java. like in predestroy logic or something

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

Inside springboot when the thread gets executed successfully then only the required method should gets executed. Otherwise in case if thread gets killed abnormally dont want to execute any method just leave like that only.
I have to handle the successful thread execution scenario only with this.

for eg.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TestWatcher extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     //do something
    }

   //like destroy or something
   public void afterThreadSuccessOnly()
   {
     //executes only on successful execution of run method.
   }
}
```

I have tried this with springboot @PreDestroy annotation but it does not work if the component is prototype.

is there any solution to achieve this scenario, please anyone help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean to define 'success' as: Did not throw an exception and ran its natural course or executed a return statement, then, what's wrong with the rather obvious:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    doJob();
    afterThreadSuccessOnly();
}

public void doJob() {
    // do something
}

public void afterThreadSuccessOnly() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot. 
that was obvious one.
but i was wondering is there any alternative way to handle that afterThreadSuccess without writing in run method..like while closing the resources type or while destroying the thred